# Java Scanner - Garbage Collection

Tags: garbage-collection, java.util.scanner

Do I need to close the Scanner in this code?

```java
public static String input(final String out){
System.out.print(out);
java.util.Scanner sc = new Java.util.Scanner(System.in);
return sc.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need to close it.  (Not even if your IDE says you do!)

The reason you don't need to is that *your code* was not responsible for opening `System.in`.  The JVM did that on startup.

The general principle is to make the code that opened a resource responsible for closing it.  In this case, `System.in` will still be accessible to other parts of your application after the call to `input` returns.  It may need to be used, but if you close it here, it can't be used.  Calling `Scanner.close()` will attempt to close whatever source it is wrapping.

---

However, your code is (possibly) wrong for another reason.  If you are going to create a `Scanner` for `System.in`, you should be doing this "globally", not in some method that could be called from lots of places.

Why?

Because you can only safely wrap a given input stream object in a `Scanner` once.

1. The `Scanner` takes control of the lifecycle of the stream.
2. The `Scanner` *may* read ahead an buffer an arbitrary number of characters from the stream making them unavailable to something else; e.g. another `Scanner`.  So two `Scanners` attempting to read from the same stream can lose characters unexpectedly.

Closing the `Scanner` will close the wrapped source, whether you do it explicitly or via *try-with-resources*.  However, a `Scanner` is not finalizable ... which means that the GC won't attempt to close the wrapped source just because a `Scanner` becomes unreachable.

Answer (score -1):

Check with

import java.util.Scanner;
    public static String input(final String out)
    { 
        String str="";
        System.out.print(out); 
          Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
       while(sc.hasNextLine()){
         str=sc.nextLine();

```
}

    return str; 
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to say here ... but I can't see how it answer's the OP's question.